# Multiple UPDATE query based on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `tbl_A` and `tabl_B`.

`tb1_A` has, among other columns, 160 columns that are named after 160 different codes e.g.  EEEPS29E

`tbl_B`, has a column of codes,  with a value for each one: the codes correspond to the 160 codes that are in `tbl_A`.

Both tables have an ID which allows you to link them together. I need to update the 160 `tbl_A` columns with values from `tbl_B`

I have a query as follows:

```
UPDATE  tbl_A
SET EEEPS29E=  COALESCE (tbl_B.value,0)
FROM
tbl_A
LEFT JOIN
tbl_B
ON
tbl_A.ID = tbl_B.ID
WHERE 
tbl_B = 'EEEPS29E'
```

I need to change this query 160 times, replacing the code, `'EEEPS29E'` in the above, to one of the other 160 codes.

Is there a way to do this in one query, or do I just have to repeat the query 160 times replacing the codes?

Comment: Looks like you have to write either 160 UPDATE statements, or as a better option, normalize your database.

Comment: You can create code table containing 160 codes and master a loop which builds and executes dynamic sql 160 times.

Comment: Normalising your design would seem the best choice here. Otherwise you're just going to have more headaches down the road.

Comment: A quick solution can be done by querying the `sys.columns` internal table to list out your tables columns and pass those to your `where` clause. However, I would focus more on what @HardCode and @Larnu suggested and look into normalizing your design.

Comment: I have never done this before: execute a dynamic SQL. I will give it a google, but do you have a simple example I could follow? This is a one off process, as the data is being prepared to  a specification before export to Stata.

Comment: Fairly easy to do in code by doing something like "set " + columname + " = " in a loop and setting the columnanme to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to update the columns in table A with the combined values in table B grouped by their column of codes? You could use `group by` and remove the `where`. Something like this:

UPDATE tbl_A 
SET EEEPS29E= COALESCE (tbl_B.value,0) 
FROM tbl_A LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ID, CodeColumn, COALESCE(value, 0) FROM tbl_B
GROUP BY ID, tbl_B.CodeColumn) B

ON tbl_A.ID = B.ID

Answer (score 0):

you can pivot the table if you already known the columns, and it will not change.

```
select
* 
from (values ('col1', '1000'), ('col2', '12'), ('col3', '12')) V(colname, val)
PIVOT (
max(val)
for colname in([col1], [col2], [col3])
) as pivoted
```

but probably it is dinamically, so you will have to create the SQL statement dinamicaly using column / table information gathered from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

something like

```
select 'update table_a set ' +
(select STRING_AGG(column_name + ' = (select value from table_b where id = table_a.id and col = '''+column_name+''')' , ' ,')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'table_a')
```